# (openmp) I get strange string, "r_saving"

Tags: c++, openmp

I practice using OpenMP, and for that purpose, I've made a very simple parallel printing program.

I have a 2d `char*` array, which I populate with following function:

```cpp
void addItem( char * arr[4][4], int row, int col ) {
    for ( int i=0; i< row; i++ ) {
        for ( int j=0; j< col; j++ ) {
            arr[i][j] = new char [10];
            strcpy( arr[i][j], "input");

            char * tmp = new char [5];
            *tmp = ( i + '0' );
            strcat( arr[i][j],tmp );
            delete [] tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

In my main function, I have the following:

```cpp
int threadNum =4;
omp_set_num_threads(threadNum);
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp for
    for ( int i=0; i<threadNum; i++ ) {
        cout << omp_get_thread_num() << endl;
        #pragma omp critical
        {
            printItem ( input, row, col );
        }
    }
}
```

What the `printItem()` function does is printing the elements of the array

```cpp
void printItem (char * arr[4][4], int row, int col) {
    for ( int i=0; i<row; i++ ) {
        cout << " row " << i << endl;
        for ( int j=0; j<col; j++ ) {
           cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

The output is

```cpp
01
row 0
input0 input0 input0 input0
row 1
input1 input1 input1 input1r_savings
row 2
input2 input2 input2 input2
row 3
input3 input3 input3 input3
32
row 0
input0 input0 input0 input0
row 1
input1 input1 input1 input1r_savings
row 2
input2 input2 input2 input2
row 3
input3 input3 input3 input3

.......
```

As you can see, in every thread's job, there is "r_savings" which I didn't add anywhere in my function.

Can you tell me where that comes from?
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue has nothing to do with OpenMP or parallelism, but all to do with C strings and their terminations.

In the following code

```cpp
arr[i][j] = new char [10];
strcpy( arr[i][j], "input");

char * tmp = new char [5];
*tmp = ( i + '0' );
strcat( arr[i][j],tmp );
delete [] tmp;
```

1. You allocate a string of 10 characters, then you copy `"input"` in it. Your string is now `{ 'i', 'n', 'p', 'u', 't', '\0', ... }` (AFAIK, the last 4 elements have undefined values).
2. Then you allocate a 5 characters string `tmp` for which you set the very first element to a character corresponding to the value if index `i`. `tmp` is now (for `i` equal zero for example) `{ '0', ... }`.
3. Did you notice that there's no `NULL` terminator to your `tmp` string? Well this is the reason of the problem. Because now, when you call `strcat()` with `tmp` as second parameter, the function doesn't know where to stop the copy. More specifically, the function will keep on copying until it finds a `NULL` character in the memory pointed by `tmp`, which might take a while, and end badly.

I will give you a quick fix for your code in the style you chosen, but since you are using C++, I would warmly recommend you to use `std::string` rather than `char*` for dealing with strings.

So this should "fix" this part of your code:

```cpp
arr[i][j] = new char[10];
sprintf( arr[i][j], "input%d", i );
```

Comment: Your hint works out perfectly. What I have done is modifying the tmp. I allocate 2 memory spaces. one for i and one for '\0'. It works out perfectly. Thank you very much. The reason why I am using c string is that I am thinking about processing time. This is just a demo. I will going to work on couple gigabyte string data soon. I think that processing cstring is faster than processing string. Isn't it?

Comment: Glad you found a solution you like. Yes, c strings will be faster to process than C++ strings, but they also are more error prone. It's up to you to see what is your primary interest between the two aspects...